# "Drag", "Pencil" or "Line" Selection

Tags: shortcut, selection-tools, select, tools

After looking around and Googling alot I couldn't find what I'm looking for, hence I'm asking here.

I'm looking for a tool that is similar to Lasso Select in some ways, but instead of :

- Drawing a line that autocompletes as a loop, selecting all verts/lines/faces that fall fully within the loop

The goal is to :

- Drawing a line (that doesn't automatically loop), selecting all verts/lines/faces that touch/cross the selection line.

I have made an example below.

What happens with Lasso Select
[image: Lasso Select]

While I would like to do the following :
[image: Drag Select]

This would make selecting complex geometry that is connected much faster, saving me from having to accurately close the loop each time.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Thanks in advance Blender Community!

Comment: Usually when I want this behaviour I use the Circle select and set the radius very low. The drawn line won't appear visually but I feel like it achieves what you are asking

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion, it's not exactly what I'm looking for but it does the job. I'm wondering if there is any Addon or 3rd party plugin that achieves this function a bit better though, any ideas?